# How Google location changes to a different location

Tags: google

Does anyone have an idea how it is possible that my phone registers a location I have never been to before?

Answer (score 1):

There are many possible reasons:

- a bug in Google's location services
- Google is using IP geo-location, which can be unreliable (e.g. when using a proxy)
- Google is using WiFi SSID geo-location which can be unreliable – I had this happen to me once, where I was logged into the private WiFi of a mobile command control room in Spain, which the week before had been set up in Australia, therefore, Google still thought the WiFi was in Australia and located me in Australia instead of Spain
- Google is using Bluetooth geo-location which can be unreliable
- A bug in your phone's GNSS receiver
- A glitch in whatever GNSS you are using